# como remover objeto do array com lodash

Tags: javascript

Pessoal quase nao uso lodash e nao estou conseguindo remover um elemento do array usando remove.
exemplo:

```
seat = { x:1, y:2 };
selectedSeats = [{ x:1, y:1 }, { x:1, y:2 }];
_.remove(selectedSeats,function(s){
    return s === seat;
})
```

ja tentei assim tambem:

```
seat = { x:1, y:2 };
selectedSeats = [{ x:1, y:1 }, { x:1, y:2 }];
_.remove(selectedSeats,function(s){
    return s.x === seat.x && s.y === seat.y;
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Primeiramente, você está a fazer comparação de objetos com `==`, que não funciona da forma que está a pensar.

Veja este pequeno exemplo:

```js
seat = { x:1, y:2 };
selectedSeats = [{ x:1, y:1 }, { x:1, y:2 }];

console.log(seat == selectedSeats[1]); //false
```

Nem sequer tem a ver com comparação forte ou fraca, e sim com o facto de ser entre objetos. Comparação entre objetos apenas dá verdadeira se ambas as referencias apontarem para o mesmo objeto. No seu caso como já está a utilizar lodash, pode utilizar o [isEqual](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.10#isEqual) do loadash para resolver este problema, que lhe vai retornar verdadeiro se ambos os objetos tiverem as mesmas propriedades e valores.

```js
seat = { x:1, y:2 };
selectedSeats = [{ x:1, y:1 }, { x:1, y:2 }];

console.log(_.isEqual(seat, selectedSeats[1])); //true
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash-compat/3.10.2/lodash.js"></script>
```

Com isto já consegue facilmente corrigir o `_.remove` para a lógica necessária:

```js
seat = { x:1, y:2 };
selectedSeats = [{ x:1, y:1 }, { x:1, y:2 }];
_.remove(selectedSeats,function(s){
    return _.isEqual(s, seat); //utiliza o isEqual para comparar
})

console.log(selectedSeats);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash-compat/3.10.2/lodash.js"></script>
```

Pode até simplificar/compactar um pouco no `remove` utilizando uma [*Arrow Function*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions):

```
_.remove(selectedSeats, s => _.isEqual(s, seat));
```

Comment: Muito bom, acabei resolvendo de outra forma, mas nao tinha visto este metodo do lodash